# Gulp.src does not consider base directory

Tags: node.js, build, gulp, build-tools

I have following stucture of the project:

```
- _build/
- build-tools/
  - gulpfile.js
- someFolder/
- excludeFolder/
- index.html
```

I want to copy all the files except `_build` and 'excludeFolder' dir to the `_build/release` directory.

I am using this gulp task:

```
gulp.src(['*',
          '!_build/**/*',
          '!build-tools/**/*',
          '!excludeFolder/**/*'],{base:'..'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_build/release'));
```

How can I command Gulp to start relative path from upper root directory, or any other directory that the gulfile.js is located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I understand the behavior your looking is `cwd`, not `base`

```
    gulp.src([
      '**',
      '!_build',
      '!_build/**',
      '!build-tools',
      '!build-tools/**',
      '!excludeFolder',
      '!excludeFolder/**'
    ],{ cwd:'..' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_build/release'), { cwd: '..' });
```

`base` is a tricky property, which aims to say to gulp where to start copying the files based on the `cwd`, but that doesn't mean that you can omit the parent folder `..` call on `gulp.src` (your case specifically).